# cellfun with conditionals in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is it possible to use cellfun with a conditional. For example, I have a 144x53 cell array, where the first four columns are of type string, the rest are floats. However, among the numbers, there are empty cells. I wonder if it is possible to use cellfun(@(x)sqrt(x), cellarray) with my array. As it is know, its not possible due to strings and empty cells. Otherwise, this is the solution that I use,

```
for n = 1:length(results)
    for k = 1:length(results(1,:))
        if ~isstr(results{n,k})
            results{n, k} = sqrt(results{n,k});
        end
    end
end
```

Otherwise, is it possible to do a vectorization here?

Comment: why don't you just filter out your string and NaNs?

Comment: look at Suever's answer, it solves it and is equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a logical array by checking if each element is numeric. And then use this to perform your `cellfun` operation on the subset of the cell array that contains numeric data.

```
C = {1, 2, 'string', 4};

% Logical array that is TRUE when the element is numeric
is_number = cellfun(@isnumeric, C);

% Perform this operation and replace only the numberic values
C(is_number) = cellfun(@sqrt, C(is_number), 'UniformOutput', 0);

%   1   1.4142    'string'    2
```

As pointed out by [@excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663057/cellfun-with-conditionals-in-matlab#comment66628664_39663101), you may also consider leaving it as a loop as it is more performant on newer versions of MATLAB (R2015b and newer).

Comment: Worth noting that the equivalent loop approach is faster in newer versions of MATLAB ([gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/1a0242681a43569e70c1f7ad82352b16))

Comment: Excellent solution

Comment: Note taken @excaza & Suever. Thanx.